# AngularJS Factory call to PHP then response back to AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

I'am not able to find the mistake. my php file returning data like ["9963648941","7416527247"], and i'am using angular factory to get the data using http call as below

```
app.factory("States", function ($http){
    var mData = {
        getStates: function(){
            return $http.get('php/usersList.php')
        }
    };
    return mData;
});
```

The States factory is using in the controller as follows

```
 app.controller('orderFormController', function($scope,$location,$rootScope,$http,States)
{
    States.getStates.then(function(response){
        console.log(JOSN.parse(response.data));
    })
});
```

Finally i'am getting error as States.getStates.then is not a function in the controller.

Comment: console.log(JOSN.parse(response.data)); its 'JSON.parse'

Comment: Not your current problem but Angular by default will parse JSON in the `response.data` property. You do not need to do it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you call the function as:

```
States.getStates().then(function(response){
    console.log(JOSN.parse(response.data));
})
```

You missed the function call brackets.

Comment: Now change it to `console.log(response.data)`

Comment: @krishna if you consider this as the correct answer then mark it as such please.

Comment: Happy that it helped you.